# Nginx proxy pass configuration docker

Tags: nginx, docker, proxypass

Here's the problem:

The host machine has multiple docker apps running on different ports for eg. App1 @ 3001, App2 @ 3002...3100 etc

Now I would like to access the apps in this format http://hostname.com/app1, http://hostname.com/app2..

To do this i'm running nginx on the host to proxy requests to the right port based on the sub-uri

```
location = /app1 {
    proxy_redirect http://hostname:3001/;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}

location ^~ /app1 {
    proxy_redirect http://hostname:3001/app1;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}
```

But this does not work when the site's sub uri changes or if the site redirects. 
For example:

```
If I visit the site at hostname:3001 -> I can see the site
If I visit the site at http://hostname.com/app1 -> I can see the site
If the site page is at hostname:3001/static/index.html then when i access it as http://hostname.com/app1 the page changes to http://hostname.com/static/index.html -> I get 404.
```

Is there a way to do this? Or is the only way to do it is to set the dns as app1.hostname.com and do a name based routing?

Comment: Your problem is not related to Docker or Nginx. It's a more generic problem of reverse proxying with changed application path: your application expects it's serving at `/` while reverse proxy serves it at `/app1`. I am sure you can find the problem description and workarounds easily.

Comment: Yup I had asked this long time back. I fixed this by creating dns record for the host where the container is running and map the container port to host port and then add a simple config to nginx map app1.abc.com to host:port in proxy pass. It has worked well and is easy to scale.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `server {}` block you want:

```
location /app1 {
    rewrite ^/app1(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://hostname:3001/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location /app2 {
    rewrite ^/app2(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://hostname:3002/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

The rewrite rule here will pass the correct uris to the ports

Answer (score 1):

You can make every app listens on a separate port (e.g. 3000 and 3001) then configure your nginx as follows (include it inside the `server {}` definition block):

```
 location /app1 {
  proxy_pass        http://localhost:3000;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
 }

 location /app2 {
  proxy_pass        http://localhost:3001;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
 }
```